# Different yup validation modes for different inputs with react

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I want to have different validation modes for different inputs. Currently, the form validation uses Yup with the `mode: "onTouched"`, but the problem is this mode applies to all inputs in the form.

I've built a demo with the same principles to demonstrate this: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-8qb0k?file=/Pokemon.js - if you click in any of the 2 inputs and then click away, the error will show (if validation fails that is). I want one of the inputs to not have an `onTouched` mode. How can this be achieved?

Currently it's set up as follows:

```
  const schema = Yup.object().shape({
    name: Yup.string()
      .required("Required")
      .min(3, "Enter at least 3 characters"),
    test: Yup.string()
      .required("Required Test")
      .min(2, "Enter at least 2 characters")
  });
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setError,
    formState: { errors },
    trigger,
    setValue,
    watch,
    clearErrors
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    mode: "onTouched"
    // reValidateMode: "onChange"
  });
```

And the form:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit /*, onError*/)}>
        <input
          {...register("name", { required: true })}
          name="name"
          placeholder="Enter a pokemon"
          onChange={onNameChange}
        />
        {errors.name && <p>{errors.name.message}</p>}
        <input
          {...register("test", { required: true })}
          name="test"
          placeholder="test"
        />
        {errors.test && <p>{errors.test.message}</p>}
        <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>
          Show Pokemon
        </button>
        {errors.namey && <p>{errors.namey.message}</p>}
      </form>
```

Thanks